# Unit test with local compare failing

Tags: javascript, dojo

Not sure why this fails for dojo

```
doh.t(formatedValue.localeCompare("16,91 $CA") === 0, "incorrect french formatting")
```

the formattedValue is definitely "16,91 $CA" so I know it's a match.  Bu twhen I try adding === 0 to the syntax, I get "Binary operation argument is not assignable to type Boolean"

I don't get it, isn't that what this is doing, evaluating to true/false when I do formatedValue.localeCompare("56,96 $CA") === 0?

Comment: why are you using localeCompare at all if you only want to test equality? I couldn't reproduce this, could you provide a minimal test case? e.g., `doh.t("foo bar".localeCompare("foo bar") === 0, "wrong!")` works fine for me...

Comment: I don't see why it would matter if you use === or .localeCompare

Comment: well, intent is the main reason it matters. localeCompare is for comparing (sorting/alphabetizing) strings and returns 0 (a falsy value) when they are equal, hence you have to use `==` or `===` as well anyway, it's far to simpler just do `===` in the first place, since you don't actually care about which string is greater than or less than.

Comment: ah so I guess I did not understand localCompare correctly.  Thanks Dave

Comment: cool, I'm still really curious to know where that error was coming from, but glad that you got things working =)

Answer (score 0):

`localeCompare` is designed for string comparison, not equality testing. By comparison, I mean testing if a string is greater or less than another string, this is useful for sorting. Since you don't want to sort the string, testing for equality is probably simpler :

```
doh.t(formatedValue === "16,91 $CA", "incorrect french formatting");
```

or even better :

```
doh.is(formatedValue, "16,91 $CA", "incorrect french formatting");
```